# How to write a program that determines its compiler

Tags: c++, c

Need to write a C program. If it is run in the C language compiler, the program should print "C". If it is run in the compiler C++, it should print "C++".

Preprocessor directives can not be used.

In head comes only to compare the size of any character with the `char` size like:

```
sizeof(char)==sizeof('a')
```

Here how it works:

```
// C code:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%s", (sizeof(char)==sizeof('a') ? "C++" : "C"));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** C

```
// C++ code:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%s", (sizeof(char)==sizeof('a') ? "C++" : "C"));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** C++

There, a better way?

Comment: Pick any of the answers to the linked question.

Comment: You can use `sizeof('a') == 1` instead, since `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.

Comment: That is a reasonable way to do the job (at least if you print a newline too). It is a whole heap simpler than what I was expecting from the title, namely determining which compiler name and version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `__cplusplus` macro to see if you're being compiled as c++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n",
#if __cplusplus
            "C++"
#else
            "C"
#endif
          );
}
```

Comment: `Preprocessor directives can not be used.`. But you might as well do the humorous `#if true` trick.

Answer (score 2):

The standard http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf
Contains an appendix on the differences between C and C++

So it contains the char vs int difference which you use but also for instance

> Change: In C++, a class declaration introduces the class name into the scope 
>               where it isdeclared and hides any object, function or other declaration
>               of that name in an enclosing scope. 
>               In C, an inner scope declaration of a struct tag name never hides the 
>               name of an object or function in an outer scope

Example: (from the standard)

```
int x [99];
void f () {
     struct x { int a ; };
     sizeof (x ); /∗ size of the array in C ∗/
                  /∗ size of the struct in C++ ∗/
}
```

To which gcc gave 396 and g++ 4 on my machine